# what is the pattern used to set the attributes of an element to a variable to acess it in the javabean using digester

Tags: xml

i am parsing an xml file using the digester , where i set the subelements to the variables of the bean using the pattern

like (" root\subelements\subsubelements ","xyz");

where xyz is the variable in the bean , and how do i set the attributes of the element to the variable in the bean like that ,

I mean what is the pattern and method i need to use in order to do so ?

> 

```
<student name="JavaGirl" division="B">
                <course>
                     <id>C3</id>
                    <name>EJB</name>
                 </course>
         </student>
```

here how do i set the name and division to the variables in the bean ?

Comment: Is this Apache Digester you're talking about?  Coding in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am parsing an xml file using the
>   digester , where i set the subelements
>   to the variables of the bean using the
>   pattern
>
> like ("
>   root\subelements\subsubelements
>   ","xyz");

I am not familiar with Digester, but if you are looking to do XPath based mapping this can easily be done with [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)

```
@XmlPath("root/subelements/subelements")
private SomeClass xyz;
```

For examples see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- [parse google geocode with xstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906855/parse-google-geocode-with-xstream/3302823#3302823)

For your particular example you could easily use JAXB:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String division;

    private Course course;
}
```

and

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Course {
   private String name;
   private String id;
}
```