# Ways of parsing an XML document to Java objects

Tags: java, xml

I am looking for different ways of parsing an XML document to Java objects.

I have an XML document, I need to parse this XML document to extract the elements and parse them in to Java objects.

Could you please recommend the following?

- different approaches
- productive parser tools for Java

Comment: Some similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276149/java-converting-xml-to-java-objects, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495336/is-there-a-declarative-way-to-parse-xml-to-java-objects

Answer (score 2):

try the solution given in this url
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'll use Groovy program a simple XML parser of the XML document using XmlSlurper and returns a map as an interface.

Or just use the Groovy to return the value

```
class XmlParseHelper {
    private def xmlNode;

    private String elementName


    public XmlParserHelper(String elementName, String xml){
        this.elementName = elementName
        xmlNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    }

    public int getTotalRows(){
        return xmlNode.table.find{it.@name == elementName}.row.size()
    }


    public String getValue(String columName, int index){
        return xmlNode.table.find{it.@name == elementName}.row[index].column.find{it.@name == columnName}.toString()
    }
}
```

and can be used like this

```
//xml is the string of the xml
XmlParseHelper xmlParseHelper = new XmlParseHelper ("mytable", xml);

        for(int i = 0; i < XmlParseHelper .getTotalRows(); i++){
            String code= xmlParseHelper.getValue("code", i);
            String name= xmlParseHelper.getValue("name", i);
.....
     }
```

This was for an specific XML, but well: it's a different approach.